# How to edit font and text styles in Cartodb infowindow?

Tags: carto, text, infowindow

I would like to change the font and text styles of the text in my Cartodb infowindow. Specifically, I'd like the name at the top to be larger font and bolded to act as an infowindow 'title' and the rest of the text to be a new font.

[image]

I haven't found a way of doing this on the online template, how can this be achieved for a beginner like me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use inline CSS code in the custom HTML option, for example:

```
  <p style="color:#FABADA;">{{country_name}}</p>
```

[image: example]

But take into account that fonts that aren't loaded in the system will not work, as adding fonts in the Custom HTML code is not allowed due to the sanitization that the custom code suffers.

Comment: thanks, is there a library of loaded fonts?